# If I have two devices(one router and one AP), can they be on different gateways or no?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point

Im building a pfsense box from my old pc. 
I'm going to use my current wireless router running tomato as an AP.

Well my question is, can each device have two different gateways and still work?
Example: My pfsense box will be 10.12.1.1 and the dhcp server will assign ips of 10.12.1.2-200

Can my AP be 10.13.1.1? Or does it need to be 10.12.1.251?

Comment: If you have two network cards in your pfsense then, I guess, you could just create a new DHCP scope and the network card card be your other gateway - basically a multi-LAN solution. you'd need to sort out any routing rules (this is where it gets complicated). Alternatively and, again, fairly complicated, if your AP supports VLANS and VLAN tagging and multiple SSIDs then you *could* create some VLANs so that your AP can have two SSIDs with different DHCP etc... Could you explain what you're trying to do to give us a better idea... your LAN size doesn't really justify the complexity...

Comment: I dont want more complicated. I want the easy route. I have an old pc and found out I can put pfsense on it so I want to do that. There isnt really a point. Its just something that sounds fun to do. I have 1 desktop on a wired connection and the rest of my home is phones and tablets. I just want to turn my pc into a pfsense router and then use my current netgear wireless router as an ap so people can still use wifi. But im trying to change my router from a router to an AP right now and I wasnt sure what to put the gateway as which is why I asked this.

Comment: Ideally your setup should look similar to this: http://i46.tinypic.com/aawsc6.jpg. Your "old PC" will need to have two network cards. The pfSense will be your network firewall and router where you'll be able to connect your Tomato router (in AP mode) to yoru pfSense via a LAN socket and you'll then be able to plug devices into the LAn sockets and have wireless...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question does not make a lot of sense in terms of routing/networking.

What you are asking to be done is possible, but probably not a sensible configuration in your network.  There is also more then 1 way to do this.

If you are wanting to have a simple "flat" network without changing the IP address of your AP you can either change the netmask so that everything is in the "10.x.x.x" range - ie set a netmask of 255.0.0.0- you will still need to change the default gateway on your AP to point to your pfsense box if you want it to be reachable outside your LAN.

You need to ensure you disable routing functionality on your AP and importantly ensure you only have 1 DHCP server - it makes sense for that DHCP server to be on the PFSense box so it can correctly provide the default gateway.

An alternative, more complex solution would be to use VLANS to provide separate networks.

THAT SAID - ALL OF THE ABOVE IS NEEDLESSLY COMPLEX AND WILL CAUSE YOU A GREAT DEAL OF TROUBLE - You are better off changing the IP address of your AP to 10.12.1.254, disabling the WAN interface on it, plugging it into your PFSense box and calling it a day - this will be a LOT easier to setup, maintain and debug.